# I am trying to do a transparency inside image kind of effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, adobe-photoshop-elements

This is what I have, I did the following effect by following the steps in this post:

[How do I make this image in image effect?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71543/how-do-i-make-this-image-in-image-effect)

Now what I am trying to do is instead of having the background in the back (in my case, the green city scape, I just want it to be transparent.) Is there a way to accomplish what I want? I tried erasing the bottom layer to make it transparent and make the top layer mode "lighten" but it doesn't do anything. I have some examples of what I am trying to accomplish if you scroll all the way to the bottom(they are the closest things I could find).

[image]

Here are some examples to sort of paint a better image of what I want. Don't be fooled by the Al Capone example (I don't want it to be cartoony, it's just an example).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Taking your example - you want the Green to be Transparent or the White? What have you tried?

Comment: I want the green to be transparent, I made that layer transparent (the green layer) but that does give me the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is different and the thought process is different but once you get to a really high level of understanding you'll know that the process is the same as this question: [How do I blend a black-background fire image in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12658/how-do-i-blend-a-black-background-fire-image-in-photoshop)

Most of the time its people wanting to remove the black or white background and leave the rest but the premise is the same and since that question was a black background my answer is also the same. If it was a white background or yours was a black background (really lighter / darker) then it would just be moving the slider in the opposite direction:

[image]