# Removing background from a complex image (doodle)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

I'm trying to remove the background from this image - http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-welcome-back-to-school-seamless-pattern-with-hand-drawn-doodle-elements-vector-illustration-302557214.jpg

I want to remove the grids and make the color 20% lighter.
I tried 20% opacity  - [http://i.imgur.com/BulovTU.png](https://i.imgur.com/BulovTU.png)
And to remove the background I used magic wand tool but it's not working...  as I'm not a professional photoshop user.
I want only which background and the doodles.

Please help me on this.

@joojaa 
Also I've this one(same pic with solid green background) - http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-welcome-back-to-school-seamless-pattern-with-hand-drawn-doodle-elements-vector-illustration-302557118.jpg
And after editing it on photoshop I got  [http://i.imgur.com/8sIfrr5.png](https://i.imgur.com/8sIfrr5.png)

Comment: it is a vector image originally its much easier to just select one bg line in say illustrator then choose select same stroke and hit delete, than to try doing this in PS. You get better results for less work.

Comment: also you would have saved yourself the work if you have bought http://m.shutterstock.com/images/302557118 instead, if you really MUST work in photoshop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12658/how-do-i-blend-a-black-background-fire-image-in-photoshop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove the background from an image?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/how-to-completely-remove-the-background-from-an-image)

Comment: Hi user70785/baalal It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Please go to our [help section](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to work with the vector in Illustrator, but if you must work in Photoshop this might help you out a little.

You can use the Select Color Range tool using setting similar to what I have here:

[image]

And then fill the selected area with white, and you should get some decent results. This is what I ended up with:

[image]

After that, just adjust the color to your liking and you should be set.